# NAPI/NACH standards compliant signing a text file using PKCS#7 in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, pkcs#7

I want to create a PKCS#7 signature for a text file in C#.

I've been following the procedure specified by the [**National Payments Corporation of India**](https://www.scribd.com/document/467141820/Annexure-I), which specifies the **National Automatic Clearing House (NACH)** signature algorithm for signing files.

Unfortunately the algorithm is only specified in Java:

> ### Text File Signing using PKCS#7 Signature in Java
>
> Steps Involved in Signing
>
> Creating Signature
>
> Java security packages can be used for the signature creation.
>
> Following are the steps we need to follow for signature creation.
>
> 1. Use a PKCS keystore (pfx file) (as specified by the certificate vendor)
> 2. Specify the signature algorithm (`SHA256WITHRSA`)
> 3. Read the file from system (original file)
> 4. Create an instance of Bouncy Castle's **CMSSignedDataGenerator** call **addSigner** API by passing private key, certificate and digest algorithm (`SHA256WITHRSA`)
> 5. Create an instance of the `java.security`. signature class with specified signature algorithm.
> 6. Use **initSign** method of **java.security.Signature** to initiate a signature with the private key of the user (private key extracted from the pfx file)
> 7. Use **update** method of **java.security.Signature** and pass the original file (without Base64 encoded)
> 8. Now use sign method of **java.security.Signature** which will return the signature in bytes
> 9. Now encode the signature with Base64 encoder
> 10. Extract the public key certificate from the keystore and encode it to Base64.
> 11. Encode the original file also into Base64.

But I need the equivalent for C#/.NET.

Does anyone know if .NET supports the NACH signing algorithm, or can anyone help me translate the the above into C#?

### Bonus Reading

- [Java Programming Forums - Signer Tool](https://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/whats-wrong-my-code/40196-signer-tool.html)
- [Code Guru - Signer Tool](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?547295-Signer-Tool)
- [NACH Project](https://www.elock.com/npcsigner.php)

Comment: I don't know who wrote that, but it specifies 2 ways of creating a signature class - a raw PKCS#1 v1.5 one that you would generate using `Signature` and one that uses `CMSSignedDataGenerator` which is named but then fully ignored. Have them give you an example signature or tell them to update their specifications, as they don't make sense. In C# you can use simply `RSA.Create()` for the barebones signature  and the CMS namespace for the latter.